# Software solution for using internal API and use external API if was not exist

Tags: php, yii, architecture

I'm building an application with API, the API is standalone module in Yii framework.

I need a way to access the API directly in the application and use it like an internal API in the same time; if the module is not exist in the application, I want to call service in the server and get the response, with no code duplication.

I have a solution but I don't like it, because the code is duplicated. Here is my solution.

Class controllerA

```
<?php 

class controllerA{

public function actionIndex(){

     $a = new A();
     $a->x();

     $b = new B();
     $b->x();

     $c = new C();
     $c->x();

}
```

Class A

```
<?php 

class A{

    public function x(){
       API_A::getInstance()->x();
    }

    public function Z(){
       API_A::getInstance()->Z();
    }

}
```

Class B

```
<?php 

class B{

    public function x(){
       API_B::getInstance()->x();
    }

    public function Z(){
       API_B::getInstance()->Z();
    }

}
```

API CLASSES:

Class B

```
<?php 

class API_B{

    public function x(){
       // CODE HERE
    }

    public function Z(){
       // CODE HERE
    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like for `A`, `B` and `C`, a corresponding API class is required. I would first inject the API instances rather than hardwiring them, possibly by creating them in the controller. For the methods `x()` and `Z()`, if their structure is the same across `A`, `B` and I expect `C`, you can put these in a parent class, since `getInstance()` can change from static (hardwired) to instance-level, and it will return the injected instance I referred to earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach in this kind of issues is to have barebone code in the controller. This means in the controller part, you will include

- Sanizitation of user input , can do it locally or through imported function.
- pass the legit input to the imported function which is part of
- format the output of internal function to json (etc) and output.

Now, The question arises where to keep the internal functions. It could be part of model but I don't prefer that because I tend to regenerate models again and again using gii.

A good way is to create components, I usually end up making one component per API controller or sometimes even a shared component across multiple controllers depending on app size.

Below is example controller action code

```
public function actionProcess1(){
     $input = \app\components\validator::sanitize(Yii::$app->request->post(),"model");
     $output = \app\components\processor::process1($input['var1'],$input['var2']);
     \app\components\formatter::getJson($output);
}
```